# d3.js bubble chart is not working Firefox browser (Error: classes is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

[image]

I have created simple d3.js bubble chart with heat colors(asp.net page), while opening firefox browser is not working. i got error **classes is not defined**. In body D3.js is referenced. please let me how to resolve the issue.

Note: The same page is working in Chrome/IE/Safari browser. Only firefox is not working.

source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .d3-tip {
            line-height: 1;
            padding: 4px 10px;
            background: whitesmoke;
            color: black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
        }

            /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip*/
            .d3-tip:after {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: inline;
                font-size: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                line-height: 1;
                color: black;
                content: "\25BC";
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
            }

            /* Style northward tooltips differently */
            .d3-tip.n:after {
                margin: -1px 0 0 0;
                top: 100%;
                left: 0;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="PopulateBubbleChart()">

    <script src="../D3js/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../D3js/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PopulateBubbleChart() {

            var json = { "name": "flare", "children": [{ "name": "US-AL", "children": [{ "name": "AL", "size": 106463, "mcperpatient": 9.11, "displayname": "Alabama" }] }, { "name": "US-AK", "children": [{ "name": "AK", "size": 14693, "mcperpatient": 12.85, "displayname": "Alaska" }] }, { "name": "US-AZ", "children": [{ "name": "AZ", "size": 137362, "mcperpatient": 9.48, "displayname": "Arizona" }] }, { "name": "US-AR", "children": [{ "name": "AR", "size": 85795, "mcperpatient": 10.27, "displayname": "Arkansas" }] }, { "name": "US-CA", "children": [{ "name": "CA", "size": 444432, "mcperpatient": 11.72, "displayname": "California" }] }, { "name": "US-CO", "children": [{ "name": "CO", "size": 90822, "mcperpatient": 9.36, "displayname": "Colorado" }] }, { "name": "US-CT", "children": [{ "name": "CT", "size": 51360, "mcperpatient": 11.1, "displayname": "Connecticut" }] }, { "name": "US-DE", "children": [{ "name": "DE", "size": 14676, "mcperpatient": 10.08, "displayname": "Delaware" }] }, { "name": "US-DC", "children": [{ "name": "DC", "size": 8800, "mcperpatient": 23.2, "displayname": "District of Columbia" }] }, { "name": "US-FL", "children": [{ "name": "FL", "size": 465279, "mcperpatient": 9.21, "displayname": "Florida" }] }, { "name": "US-GA", "children": [{ "name": "GA", "size": 167445, "mcperpatient": 8.4, "displayname": "Georgia" }] }, { "name": "US-HI", "children": [{ "name": "HI", "size": 23824, "mcperpatient": 10.21, "displayname": "Hawaii" }] }, { "name": "US-ID", "children": [{ "name": "ID", "size": 39928, "mcperpatient": 8.33, "displayname": "Idaho" }] }, { "name": "US-IL", "children": [{ "name": "IL", "size": 173998, "mcperpatient": 10.92, "displayname": "Illinois" }] }, { "name": "US-IN", "children": [{ "name": "IN", "size": 122936, "mcperpatient": 9.13, "displayname": "Indiana" }] }, { "name": "US-IA", "children": [{ "name": "IA", "size": 71758, "mcperpatient": 8.09, "displayname": "Iowa" }] }, { "name": "US-KS", "children": [{ "name": "KS", "size": 58097, "mcperpatient": 9.64, "displayname": "Kansas" }] }, { "name": "US-KY", "children": [{ "name": "KY", "size": 101096, "mcperpatient": 9.28, "displayname": "Kentucky" }] }, { "name": "US-LA", "children": [{ "name": "LA", "size": 76489, "mcperpatient": 9.56, "displayname": "Louisiana" }] }, { "name": "US-ME", "children": [{ "name": "ME", "size": 39358, "mcperpatient": 8.52, "displayname": "Maine" }] }, { "name": "US-MD", "children": [{ "name": "MD", "size": 53461, "mcperpatient": 10.43, "displayname": "Maryland" }] }, { "name": "US-MA", "children": [{ "name": "MA", "size": 84345, "mcperpatient": 13.02, "displayname": "Massachusetts" }] }, { "name": "US-MI", "children": [{ "name": "MI", "size": 142558, "mcperpatient": 9.46, "displayname": "Michigan" }] }, { "name": "US-MN", "children": [{ "name": "MN", "size": 108274, "mcperpatient": 9.69, "displayname": "Minnesota" }] }, { "name": "US-MS", "children": [{ "name": "MS", "size": 69676, "mcperpatient": 9.49, "displayname": "Mississippi" }] }, { "name": "US-MO", "children": [{ "name": "MO", "size": 109455, "mcperpatient": 8.59, "displayname": "Missouri" }] }, { "name": "US-MT", "children": [{ "name": "MT", "size": 35189, "mcperpatient": 8.6, "displayname": "Montana" }] }, { "name": "US-NE", "children": [{ "name": "NE", "size": 47275, "mcperpatient": 8.74, "displayname": "Nebraska" }] }, { "name": "US-NV", "children": [{ "name": "NV", "size": 65443, "mcperpatient": 12.04, "displayname": "Nevada" }] }, { "name": "US-NH", "children": [{ "name": "NH", "size": 28604, "mcperpatient": 9.73, "displayname": "New Hampshire" }] }, { "name": "US-NJ", "children": [{ "name": "NJ", "size": 77179, "mcperpatient": 9.71, "displayname": "New Jersey" }] }, { "name": "US-NM", "children": [{ "name": "NM", "size": 48781, "mcperpatient": 10.18, "displayname": "New Mexico" }] }, { "name": "US-NY", "children": [{ "name": "NY", "size": 228820, "mcperpatient": 12.33, "displayname": "New York" }] }, { "name": "US-NC", "children": [{ "name": "NC", "size": 205006, "mcperpatient": 8.73, "displayname": "North Carolina" }] }, { "name": "US-ND", "children": [{ "name": "ND", "size": 18416, "mcperpatient": 8.07, "displayname": "North Dakota" }] }, { "name": "US-OH", "children": [{ "name": "OH", "size": 223944, "mcperpatient": 9.88, "displayname": "Ohio" }] }, { "name": "US-OK", "children": [{ "name": "OK", "size": 90731, "mcperpatient": 8.22, "displayname": "Oklahoma" }] }, { "name": "US-OR", "children": [{ "name": "OR", "size": 96190, "mcperpatient": 9.97, "displayname": "Oregon" }] }, { "name": "US-PA", "children": [{ "name": "PA", "size": 232054, "mcperpatient": 9.07, "displayname": "Pennsylvania" }] }, { "name": "US-RI", "children": [{ "name": "RI", "size": 20132, "mcperpatient": 10.76, "displayname": "Rhode Island" }] }, { "name": "US-SC", "children": [{ "name": "SC", "size": 123070, "mcperpatient": 8.13, "displayname": "South Carolina" }] }, { "name": "US-SD", "children": [{ "name": "SD", "size": 29744, "mcperpatient": 10.32, "displayname": "South Dakota" }] }, { "name": "US-TN", "children": [{ "name": "TN", "size": 135220, "mcperpatient": 9.79, "displayname": "Tennessee" }] }, { "name": "US-TX", "children": [{ "name": "TX", "size": 434233, "mcperpatient": 9.18, "displayname": "Texas" }] }, { "name": "US-UT", "children": [{ "name": "UT", "size": 34062, "mcperpatient": 11.19, "displayname": "Utah" }] }, { "name": "US-VT", "children": [{ "name": "VT", "size": 14925, "mcperpatient": 8.51, "displayname": "Vermont" }] }, { "name": "US-VA", "children": [{ "name": "VA", "size": 87478, "mcperpatient": 9.06, "displayname": "Virginia" }] }, { "name": "US-WA", "children": [{ "name": "WA", "size": 118461, "mcperpatient": 9.17, "displayname": "Washington" }] }, { "name": "US-WV", "children": [{ "name": "WV", "size": 58733, "mcperpatient": 11.12, "displayname": "West Virginia" }] }, { "name": "US-WI", "children": [{ "name": "WI", "size": 117000, "mcperpatient": 10.14, "displayname": "Wisconsin" }] }, { "name": "US-WY", "children": [{ "name": "WY", "size": 18583, "mcperpatient": 10.14, "displayname": "Wyoming" }] }], "minvalue": 8.07, "maxvalue": 23.2, "statecounty": "State" }

            $('#mapdiv3').empty();
            var color = ["#4F9A85", '#79A163', '#F0C26A', '#C26B50']
            try {
                var r = 325,
                    format = d3.format(",d"),
                    colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
                    .domain([json.minvalue, json.maxvalue])
                    .range(color);

                var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                    .sort(null)
                    .size([r, r])
                    .padding(1);

                var tip = d3.tip()
                .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                .offset([-10, 0])
                .html(function (d) {
                    return json.statecounty + ": <strong>" + d.dispname + "</strong> <br/> Unique Patients**: <strong>" + format(d.value) + "</strong> <br/> Med per Patient: <strong>$" + d.sc + "</strong> <br/>";
                })

                var vis = d3.select("#mapdiv3").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", r)
                    .attr("height", r)
                    .attr("class", "bubble");

                vis.call(tip);

                var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(bubble.nodes(classes(json))
                    .filter(function (d) { return !d.children; }))
                  .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
                    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

                //node.append("title")
                //    .text(function (d) // { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });
                //    { return "Name: <strong>" + d.className + "</strong> <br/> Unique Patients: <strong>" + format(d.value) + "</strong> <br/> Medical Care per Patient: <strong>" + d.sc + "</strong> <br/>"; });


                node.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
                    .style("fill", function (d) { return colorScale(d.sc); });


                node.append("text")
                    .attr("dy", ".3em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function (d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3) });

                // Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
                function classes(root) {
                    var classes = [];

                    function recurse(name, node) {
                        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function (child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
                        else {
                            classes.push({ packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size, sc: node.mcperpatient, dispname: node.displayname });
                        }
                    }

                    recurse(null, root);
                    return { children: classes };
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert( err.message);
            }

        }
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="mapdiv3" style="height: 300px; width=400px; border: none; text-align: center"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the scripts in the HTML head also..

You have the classes function nested in the PopulateBubbleChart function, you likely want to put that on the outside of that function.  You then have a similar issue with recurse function.  You also do not want to name your function the same name as your array.

You had several issues:  here is a jsfiddle you can use to re-piece your code together again: http://jsfiddle.net/ouzo4rje/1/

HTML

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../D3js/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../D3js/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="PopulateBubbleChart()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="mapdiv3" style="height: 300px; width: 400px; border: none; text-align: center;"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.d3-tip {
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
}
/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip*/
 .d3-tip:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    content:"\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Style northward tooltips differently */
 .d3-tip.n:after {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

JS

```
function PopulateBubbleChart() {

    var json = {
        "name": "flare",
            "children": [{
            "name": "US-AL",
                "children": [{
                "name": "AL",
                    "size": 106463,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.11,
                    "displayname": "Alabama"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-AK",
                "children": [{
                "name": "AK",
                    "size": 14693,
                    "mcperpatient": 12.85,
                    "displayname": "Alaska"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-AZ",
                "children": [{
                "name": "AZ",
                    "size": 137362,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.48,
                    "displayname": "Arizona"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-AR",
                "children": [{
                "name": "AR",
                    "size": 85795,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.27,
                    "displayname": "Arkansas"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-CA",
                "children": [{
                "name": "CA",
                    "size": 444432,
                    "mcperpatient": 11.72,
                    "displayname": "California"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-CO",
                "children": [{
                "name": "CO",
                    "size": 90822,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.36,
                    "displayname": "Colorado"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-CT",
                "children": [{
                "name": "CT",
                    "size": 51360,
                    "mcperpatient": 11.1,
                    "displayname": "Connecticut"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-DE",
                "children": [{
                "name": "DE",
                    "size": 14676,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.08,
                    "displayname": "Delaware"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-DC",
                "children": [{
                "name": "DC",
                    "size": 8800,
                    "mcperpatient": 23.2,
                    "displayname": "District of Columbia"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-FL",
                "children": [{
                "name": "FL",
                    "size": 465279,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.21,
                    "displayname": "Florida"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-GA",
                "children": [{
                "name": "GA",
                    "size": 167445,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.4,
                    "displayname": "Georgia"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-HI",
                "children": [{
                "name": "HI",
                    "size": 23824,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.21,
                    "displayname": "Hawaii"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-ID",
                "children": [{
                "name": "ID",
                    "size": 39928,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.33,
                    "displayname": "Idaho"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-IL",
                "children": [{
                "name": "IL",
                    "size": 173998,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.92,
                    "displayname": "Illinois"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-IN",
                "children": [{
                "name": "IN",
                    "size": 122936,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.13,
                    "displayname": "Indiana"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-IA",
                "children": [{
                "name": "IA",
                    "size": 71758,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.09,
                    "displayname": "Iowa"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-KS",
                "children": [{
                "name": "KS",
                    "size": 58097,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.64,
                    "displayname": "Kansas"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-KY",
                "children": [{
                "name": "KY",
                    "size": 101096,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.28,
                    "displayname": "Kentucky"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-LA",
                "children": [{
                "name": "LA",
                    "size": 76489,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.56,
                    "displayname": "Louisiana"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-ME",
                "children": [{
                "name": "ME",
                    "size": 39358,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.52,
                    "displayname": "Maine"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-MD",
                "children": [{
                "name": "MD",
                    "size": 53461,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.43,
                    "displayname": "Maryland"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-MA",
                "children": [{
                "name": "MA",
                    "size": 84345,
                    "mcperpatient": 13.02,
                    "displayname": "Massachusetts"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-MI",
                "children": [{
                "name": "MI",
                    "size": 142558,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.46,
                    "displayname": "Michigan"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-MN",
                "children": [{
                "name": "MN",
                    "size": 108274,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.69,
                    "displayname": "Minnesota"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-MS",
                "children": [{
                "name": "MS",
                    "size": 69676,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.49,
                    "displayname": "Mississippi"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-MO",
                "children": [{
                "name": "MO",
                    "size": 109455,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.59,
                    "displayname": "Missouri"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-MT",
                "children": [{
                "name": "MT",
                    "size": 35189,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.6,
                    "displayname": "Montana"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-NE",
                "children": [{
                "name": "NE",
                    "size": 47275,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.74,
                    "displayname": "Nebraska"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-NV",
                "children": [{
                "name": "NV",
                    "size": 65443,
                    "mcperpatient": 12.04,
                    "displayname": "Nevada"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-NH",
                "children": [{
                "name": "NH",
                    "size": 28604,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.73,
                    "displayname": "New Hampshire"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-NJ",
                "children": [{
                "name": "NJ",
                    "size": 77179,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.71,
                    "displayname": "New Jersey"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-NM",
                "children": [{
                "name": "NM",
                    "size": 48781,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.18,
                    "displayname": "New Mexico"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-NY",
                "children": [{
                "name": "NY",
                    "size": 228820,
                    "mcperpatient": 12.33,
                    "displayname": "New York"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-NC",
                "children": [{
                "name": "NC",
                    "size": 205006,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.73,
                    "displayname": "North Carolina"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-ND",
                "children": [{
                "name": "ND",
                    "size": 18416,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.07,
                    "displayname": "North Dakota"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-OH",
                "children": [{
                "name": "OH",
                    "size": 223944,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.88,
                    "displayname": "Ohio"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-OK",
                "children": [{
                "name": "OK",
                    "size": 90731,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.22,
                    "displayname": "Oklahoma"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-OR",
                "children": [{
                "name": "OR",
                    "size": 96190,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.97,
                    "displayname": "Oregon"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-PA",
                "children": [{
                "name": "PA",
                    "size": 232054,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.07,
                    "displayname": "Pennsylvania"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-RI",
                "children": [{
                "name": "RI",
                    "size": 20132,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.76,
                    "displayname": "Rhode Island"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-SC",
                "children": [{
                "name": "SC",
                    "size": 123070,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.13,
                    "displayname": "South Carolina"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-SD",
                "children": [{
                "name": "SD",
                    "size": 29744,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.32,
                    "displayname": "South Dakota"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-TN",
                "children": [{
                "name": "TN",
                    "size": 135220,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.79,
                    "displayname": "Tennessee"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-TX",
                "children": [{
                "name": "TX",
                    "size": 434233,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.18,
                    "displayname": "Texas"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-UT",
                "children": [{
                "name": "UT",
                    "size": 34062,
                    "mcperpatient": 11.19,
                    "displayname": "Utah"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-VT",
                "children": [{
                "name": "VT",
                    "size": 14925,
                    "mcperpatient": 8.51,
                    "displayname": "Vermont"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-VA",
                "children": [{
                "name": "VA",
                    "size": 87478,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.06,
                    "displayname": "Virginia"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-WA",
                "children": [{
                "name": "WA",
                    "size": 118461,
                    "mcperpatient": 9.17,
                    "displayname": "Washington"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-WV",
                "children": [{
                "name": "WV",
                    "size": 58733,
                    "mcperpatient": 11.12,
                    "displayname": "West Virginia"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-WI",
                "children": [{
                "name": "WI",
                    "size": 117000,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.14,
                    "displayname": "Wisconsin"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "US-WY",
                "children": [{
                "name": "WY",
                    "size": 18583,
                    "mcperpatient": 10.14,
                    "displayname": "Wyoming"
            }]
        }],
            "minvalue": 8.07,
            "maxvalue": 23.2,
            "statecounty": "State"
    }

    $('#mapdiv3').empty();
    var color = ["#4F9A85", '#79A163', '#F0C26A', '#C26B50']
    try {
        var r = 325,
            format = d3.format(",d"),
            colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
                .domain([json.minvalue, json.maxvalue])
                .range(color);

        var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
            .sort(null)
            .size([r, r])
            .padding(1);

        var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function (d) {
            return json.statecounty + ": <strong>" + d.dispname + "</strong> <br/> Unique Patients**: <strong>" + format(d.value) + "</strong> <br/> Med per Patient: <strong>$" + d.sc + "</strong> <br/>";
        });

        var vis = d3.select("#mapdiv3").append("svg")
            .attr("width", r)
            .attr("height", r)
            .attr("class", "bubble");

        vis.call(tip);

        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(bubble.nodes(classes(json))
            .filter(function (d) {
            return !d.children;
        }))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        })
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

        //node.append("title")
        //    .text(function (d) // { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });
        //    { return "Name: <strong>" + d.className + "</strong> <br/> Unique Patients: <strong>" + format(d.value) + "</strong> <br/> Medical Care per Patient: <strong>" + d.sc + "</strong> <br/>"; });


        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function (d) {
            return d.r;
        })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
            return colorScale(d.sc);
        });


        node.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".3em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) {
            return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3)
        });


    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }

}

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
var arrClasses = [];

function classes(root) {

    recurse(null, root);
    return {
        children: arrClasses
    };
}

function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children) {
        node.children.forEach(function (child) {
            recurse(node.name, child);
        });
    } else {
        arrClasses.push({
            packageName: name,
            className: node.name,
            value: node.size,
            sc: node.mcperpatient,
            dispname: node.displayname
        });
    }
}
```